# How to get recent history pages in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How and where are the recent history stored, like the pages that load when back button is pressed. It doesn't load the url but have cached the pages from previous visit. I want to know if I can get that pages, manipulate it, or add pages into that stack, so when I press back a different page is loaded, not by loading the url, of the page that I want, but an already loaded page.

I can only add URLs to history stack, so when back is pressed, different pages are loaded after fetching with url. I need to be able to add whole page itself, so when I press back, the page should load locally without fetching from server.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There's no way.